# Extracting href from a class within other h3/class classes with jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I'm trying to get the `href` attribute from  **div.class yt-lockup-content**, but it's returning `null` what I doing wrong?

```
<div class="yt-lockup-content">

        <h3 class="yt-lockup-title "><a class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link  spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" dir="ltr" title="Live ::   PTV Sports Official Live Transmission"  data-sessionlink="ei=K8uGWMHkGMWjcp7dhNAJ&amp;feature=c4-live-promo" href="/watch?v=8M00cos0d_0">Live ::   PTV Sports Official Live Transmission</a></h3>
```

This code I tried so far:

```
rssDocument = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0KT03NPnN-j4HGzetW9Lpw/featured").timeout(6000).ignoreContentType(true).parser(Parser.htmlParser()).get();
                Elements firstH1 = rssDocument.select("div.yt-lockup-content > h3 > a");
```

I need get this url: `href="/watch?v=8M00cos0d_0"`

Answer (score 2):

An option could be to read the attribute after the select:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements link = doc.select("div.yt-lockup-content > h3 > a");
String hrefAttribute = link.attr("href");
System.out.println(hrefAttribute);
```

Output:

> /watch?v=8M00cos0d_0